# Basic Java: Finding the Greatest Common Factor

Tags: java

**I need to create a program that finds the greatest common factor of two user entered numbers using this formula:**

gcd(x, y) = gcd(x – y, y) if x >= y and gcd(x, y) = gcd(x,y-x) if x < y.

For example:
gcd(72, 54) = gcd(72 – 54, 54) = gcd(18, 54)Since 72 > 54, we replace 72 with 72 – 54 = 18 and continue the loop with the new values

Iteration 2: gcd(18, 54) = gcd(18, 54 – 18) = gcd(18, 36)
Since 18 < 54, we replace 54 with 54 – 18 = 36 and continue the loop with the new values

Iteration 3: gcd(18, 36) = gcd(18, 36 – 18) = gcd(18, 18)
Since 18 < 36, we replace 36 with 36 – 18 = 18 and continue the loop with the new values

Iteration 4: gcd(18, 18) = gcd(18 – 18, 18) = gcd(0, 18) = 18
Since 18 >= 18, we replace the first 18 with 18 – 18 = 0
Since one of the values is 0 we do not continue the loop
The nonzero value, 18, is the gcd.

Here's of the code I have so far:

[image]

I'm getting the error "Illegal start of expression."

Comment: It doesn't need to involve a while loop, you can use recursion too.

Comment: Start by writing some code...test it...find an error...troubleshoot...write more code...

Comment: What you are writing looks like a recursive function. Write that function, and see if it works. Post your code, the results you get, the results you expect. At that point you will get help.

Comment: At least tag it as homework, we aren't here to do your schoolwork for you.

Comment: @dmcnelis "homework" tag is deprecated.

Comment: @dmcnelis - `homework` tag is long deprecated

Comment: Write out a plan of what the requirements are in your own words. Write down each step in solving the problem. Break out pieces that are their own functionality. Defined what they need to perform their action (inputs) and what the expected outcome will be. Those actions are your methods.

Comment: Edited, sorry forgot to add the code.

Comment: Use Math.Max(num1, num2) - Math.Min(num1,num2) instead of num1-num2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all in your logic here:

```
do {
   int gcd1 = (num1-num2);
   System.out.println(gcd1 + "," + num2);

   }
   while (num1 != 0 && num2 != 0);
   return
}
```

You are just printing out gcd1 and num2 without updating num1 and num2.

Also think how you can use recursion to tackle this problem.

If you insist on using a loop, here's the while loop logic:

```
public static int greatestCommon(int a, int b)
        {
            while (a != 0 && b != 0)
            {
                if (a >= b)
                {
                    a = a - b;
                }
                else
                    b = b - a;
            }
            if (a == 0) return b;
            else return a;
        }
```

note that you do not need to use a do-while loop since there are situations when you do not need the substraction (if one or both of them are 0).

Comment: I need to use a loop for this problem.

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
Math.Max(num1, num2) - Math.Min(num1,num2)
```

instead of `num1-num2`

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you tell me what's wrong with my method (In the edit up top)

Comment: Its telling me illegal start of expression on the line with the first curly bracket at the bottom. I believe it has something to do with the return statement

Answer (score 0):

You've already stated the answer (the algorithm) in your first sentence:

`gcd(x, y) = gcd(x – y, y) if x >= y and gcd(x, y) = gcd(x,y-x) if x < y.`

So how to translate that into code?  The left-hand side of the equation is your method prototype, and the right-hand side is your method body:

```
public static int gcd(x, y)  // doesn't HAVE to be public or static
{
  gcd(x – y, y) if x >= y and gcd(x, y) = gcd(x,y-x) if x < y
}
```

but that code in the body doesn't compile, so you need to rewrite the body. Note that `"and gcd(x, y) = ..."` is a repetition of the method prototype and thus removed:

```
public static int gcd(x, y)
{
  if (x >= y)
  {
    return ... // you fill this in
  }
  else if (x < y)
  {
    return ... // you fill this in
  }
}
```

Note that the final "else-if" check really isn't necessary, but you teacher likely wants to see it there.

**EDIT:**

Since this likely a classroom exercise in recursion, consider this working example taken from `javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel`:

```
private static int gcd(int i, int j)
{
  return (j == 0) ? i : gcd(j, i%j);
}
```

**SIDENOTE: Don't turn this in, as it obviously is not derived from the algorithm given to you, and your teacher will likely mark it wrong.**

Since you may not have learned the ternary operator syntax, I'll rewrite it as:

```
private static int gcd(int i, int j)
{
  if (j == 0)
    return i;
  else
    return gcd(j, i%j);
}
```

This is an example of recursion, where under certain circumstances we can return a known value, but otherwise the method has to call itself again with a different set of parameters.

**EDIT 2:**

Since an interative approach is needed in lieu of a recursive one, remember that all recursive methods can be rewritten using iteration (i.e., via loops).

Further reading:

[Refactoring: Replace Recursion With Iteration](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceRecursionWithIteration.html)

Comment: Would Math.Max(num1,num2)-Math.Min(num1,num2) work just as well?

Comment: The statement essentially says, `subtract the smaller number from the bigger number`. I'm not sure what that result is going to buy you (hint: you don't need to do this)

Comment: Could you see what the issue with my method is? Its giving me the error "error class, interface, or enum expected"

Comment: The method names from the Math class should be `max` and `min`, not `Max` and `Min` (note the erroneous capitalization), and the method requires you to return an `int` but you're not returning anything.

Comment: Ok thanks for catching the errors. I can't use recursion it has to be through loops. If I wanted to return the two integers would it be return int? And where would return int go?

Comment: To use loops, get the recursive solution working (the one I posted for you is 99% complete). Then, see edit 2 above.